# ASP.Net validation controls behaviour

Tags: asp.net, validation

Asp.net validation controls generates client-side javascript that validates controls.

I decided to have a look into the ASP.NET validation JavaScript and I can see there is a function that hooks into the onchange events for controls to make sure the validation script runs when a values is changed.

**My question:**

Is there a way to disable this onchange validation? I want the validation to be done on the submit and then show the necessary error messages.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply set:

```
EnableClientScript="False"
```

On the control.

Comment: I think Morph still wants client side validation

Comment: Oh, right. Well, @OP, what control is automatically posting back on change? Just stop it.